# How to correctly deal with cyrillic encoding in Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, encoding

I am anticipating my question is about to be closed down as exact duplicate but nevertheless.

I need to display cyrillic text in HTML

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('wp-login.php?action=register', 'login'); ?>"> регистрация</a>
```

However on the web I can see 'squares' if UTF-8 encoding is chosen. If I change encoding to Windows Cyrillic then link text is ok but all WordPress cyrillic contents is not displayed correctly.

So - I've got wordpress contents and HTML/PHP in different encodings. Do I have to save PHP in Windows Cyrillic or there is better solution?

I am using Notepad++.

Comment: Can  you clarify what happens when you choose UTF-8. Does the WP content work then? What other content do you have?

Comment: You have to save file with cyrylic text in `UTF-8` encoding. Is it ?

Comment: Pekka, In UTF-8 Wp content do work (both titles and stuff). But PHP hardcoded text is displayed as 'squares'. In Windows Cyrillic WP is displayed as "РҐРѕС‡Сѓ РєСѓРїРёС‚СЊ С‚Р°РєРёРµ Р±РѕС‚РёРЅРєРё "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should save your file in `UTF-8` instead of cyrillic, then the output will be rendered correctly.

Check your editor that it can save `UTF-8` files and set the encoding correctly in it.

Comment: And the file should be saved as UTF-8 without BOM